# Prevent redirect to admin/structure/types after adding content type

Tags: nodes, redirection, forms

Whenever I submit a form at e.g. `admin/structure/types/add`, or `admin/structure/types/manage/article`, or `admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields`, I am redirected to the `admin/structure/types` overview page. This is quite annoying.

Is there any existing solution to prevent this redirect?

I know I can use `hook_form_alter()`, but I was wondering if others feel the same way, and if maybe someone has created a module for it.

If enough people share my pain, I might even do it myself :)

Comment: I share your pain... maybe rules would do it?

Comment: Probably, but I don't want to configure my rules on every new site. I would much rather just enable a module.

Comment: `hook_form_alter()` is the existing solution as far as I know, it's about 6 lines of code so I doubt there's a contrib module for it ;)

Comment: Maybe worth a patch for Drupal 8 too if it still happens there (maybe it could even be considered for back-porting).

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/save_edit is interesting, though it is for node forms not for content type edit forms.